# The equals sign is missing

Tags: fonts, math-mode, symbols

When I use the fonts `fourier` and `iwona` at the same time, the equals sign `=` does not appear. For example, the source

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[math]{iwona}
\begin{document}
$A=B$
\end{document}
```

produces

```
A B
```

**Question: How can I fix this problem?**

(*) I want to use `iwona` and to replace fonts for `\mathbb` with ones of `fourier`.

Remarks:

1. If I use the package `fourier` first, then `=`  appears as usual. But all of the fonts are replaced by `fourier` fonts, so this is not the solution which I want.
2. The following error could relate to the problem.

   > LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/iwonam/m/n' undefined (Font)
   >
   >   using`OT1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 5.
   >
   > LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
3. If I use only `iwona` then the equals sign appears.
4. If there is a way to satisfy (*), please let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can load only the `\mathbb` alphabet from `fourier`:

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{futm}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{futm}{m}{n}{
  <-> fourier-bb % changed from .92 to 1
  }{}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{U}{futm}{m}{n}
```

Note that I've also changed the magnification from `.92` to `1` to match `iwona` sizes.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math]{iwona}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{futm}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{futm}{m}{n}{
  <-> fourier-bb % changed from .92 to 1
  }{}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{U}{futm}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
$A(x)=B(x),\quad x\in\mathbb{R}$ 
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: `s*[1]` doesn't harm, but removing it is more efficient.